# NSUserDefaults value not being set

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to set a BOOL to a key in NSUserDefaults, but it doesn't seem to be working as I am getting the `NSLog(@"called");` showing up in console every launch. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me where I am going wrong.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        CheckBox*btn = [[CheckBox alloc] init];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        [btn setTag:i];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", btn.tag]] ? @"checkbox.png":@"checkbox-pressed.png"];
        [btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_checkboxArray addObject:btn];
        [btn release];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
    }
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kFL]) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        NSMutableArray *custArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < [_checkboxArray count]; i ++) {
            CheckBox *c = (CheckBox *)[_checkboxArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [c setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [c tag]]];
            [custArr addObject:c];
        }
        [_checkboxArray removeAllObjects];
        [_checkboxArray addObjectsFromArray:custArr];
        [custArr release];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"called");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kFL];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

After you make any changes